# ¿Cómo cambiar el resultado de una calculadora por el valor de un boton presionado a posteriori? Jswing

Tags: java, backend

estoy haciendo una calculadora en Jswing y cuando por ejemplo sumo dos numeros, efectivamente me da el valor esperado pero cuando presiono un nuevo digito despues de qué la respuesta haya sido calculada, el valor del digito se concatena con la respuesta.

He estado buscando y he visto que usando los metodos .getModel().isPressed() se podría simular esta función de presionado (Puedo estar equivocado) y lo he razonado cómo: "Si en uno de los botones númericos, se presiona el Boton del IGUAL (Yo lo llamo ButtonEqual) entonces que cuando se presione de nuevo el mismo botón númerico, se imprima en el Textfield sin concatenar (Esto con el metodo de TextField .setText)".

Pero no me da :/, me sigue concatenando

Función del Botón Igual:

```
    private void ButtonEQUALActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if(TextField.getText().contains("+")){
            String[] text_split = TextField.getText().split("\\+");
            int acomuladorsum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < text_split.length; i++){
                acomuladorsum = acomuladorsum + Integer.parseInt(text_split[i]);
                TextField.setText(Integer.toString(acomuladorsum));
            }
        }
      }
```

Función Boton #2

```
    private void Button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        TextField.setText(TextField.getText() + Integer.toString(2));
        if(ButtonEQUAL.getModel().isPressed()){
            if(Button2.getModel().isPressed()){
                TextField.setText(Integer.toString(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

En resumen, cómo haría para evitar qué se me concatene la respuesta con el digito qué presiono despues de qué esta se muestra? se podría resolver desde mi razonamiento planteado?

PD: Perdón por tanto texto, si no me entendieron, estaré pendiente para responder sus dudas :D. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

te recomendaria crearte una funcion para limpiar el output del resultado.

```
public void limpiar(){
    setText("");
}
```

Esta funcion se la aplicas

> TextField.limpiar();

Y antes de aplicarla te guardas el resultado de la operación anterior y la vuelves a aplicar después de que el usuario presione otro numero.